# Using mocha under VSTS CI produces ugly output formatting

Tags: angular, mocha.js, karma-runner, azure-pipelines

I have Angular tests running through PhantomJS, and using Mocha as reporter.

But once the tests are run under VSTS, the output is quite ugly, it cannot resolve both color and icons.

Result on my computer running Cmder or on Mac/Linux terminal:

[image: Result on computer]

Result under vsts:

```
2017-05-11T15:37:56.0776810Z [32m    [32m√[32m should be initialized[39m
2017-05-11T15:37:56.0786809Z [32m    [32m√[32m should bootstrap the app content via <router-outlet>[39m
```

How to make VSTS render tests in a proper way, handling colors and icons of Mocha?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn’t the feature to change build log format.

You can try to create custom build result extension to display report result according to detail requirement.

[image]

[Overview of integrating with Visual Studio Team Services](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/overview)

[vsts-extension-samples](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-extension-samples)